# bash, как и чем переименовать группу файлов?

Tags: bash, sed, awk, rename

```
Подскажите код, переименовать группу файлов?
К примеру, сейчас так:
Princess of the Dawn - Accept.mp3
Cradle Of Love - Billy Idol.mp3   
Sweet Sixteen - Billy Idol.mp3
Livin On A Prayer - Bon Jovi.mp3  
Runaway - Bon Jovi.mp3
The Unforgiven - Metallica.mp3
Send Me An Angel - Scorpions.mp3
Still Loving - Scorpions.mp3

Хочу так:
Accept - Princess of the Dawn.mp3
Accept - Time Machine.mp3
Billy Idol - Cradle Of Love.mp3
Billy Idol - Sweet Sixteen.mp3
Bon Jovi - Livin On A Prayer.mp3
Bon Jovi - Runaway.mp3
Metallica - Nothing Else Matters.mp3
Metallica - The Unforgiven.mp3
Scorpions - Send Me An Angel.mp3
Scorpions - Still Loving.mp3

P.S чем лучше это делать: sed, awk, rename, basename?
Система macOS.
```

Comment: Все это довольно просто (особенно, если отказаться от `sed\awk` в пользу `python`), но ровно до того момента, когда символ дефиса появляется в названии исполнителя или в имени трека или одновременно и там и там.

Comment: @user207200 , не будет проблемой, если в имени трека или композитора не будет пробелов вокруг дефиса

Comment: @Alexandr Вот кто бы это мог гарантировать? И почему бы им там не быть?

Comment: как-то так.
https://youtu.be/tuzRjA271hA?t=333 — моих знаний не хватило, несколько дней провозился...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls | awk -F'( - )|[.]' '{system("mv \""$0"\" \""$2" - "$1"."$3"\"")}'
```

здесь мы используем два разделителя полей, один " - " а второй точка "."

В названии трека данные разделители должны встречаться единожды, а иначе *может пойти что-то не так*.